# Using an arduino board to control a atercooling loop within a pc

Tags: arduino

This is an exploratory question really (I am new to arduino / programing ) but I am curious as to weather an arduino board could be programmed with C++ to automatically control the rate of flow of the pump or fan speed ect. to dynamically control and hopefully improve cooling. In addition to this could the Arduino board support a small LCD screen so that real time temperature readouts could be given (I plan to have numerous temperature sensors placed on components? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this does seem feasible. The challenge here might be the temperature measurement. Many of the cheap temperature/humidity sensors that are used with the arduino are actually very slow to register changes in temperature. You may want to do some research on this. Luckily you can do some experiments with temperature measurement and an arduino pretty simply, taking the output of the temperature measurement on the arduino IDE serial console.

The LCD, pump and the fan control is a are pretty widespread and it should be easy to find documentation on those.

Comment: How should I go about constructing a user interface for my LCD? Should I use assembly to write a kernel and then code the rest with C++ and would an Uno run this successfully?